# QFile overwrite only at secont time

Tags: qt, qfile

The code can be found below.

```
QFile *fd = new QFile();
fd->setFileName("TEST.txt");
fd->open(QIODevice::ReadWrite);
if(fd->exists() == true){
ui->textEdit->append("OK");}
ui->textEdit->append(QString::number(fd->write("Additional string")));
```

At textEdit canvas I receive the count of written chars, but it does not appear in file. After the second call of fd-> write(...) everything is fine, but why only at second time?

Comment: What is your code supposed to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The files are buffered, executing a `write` doesn't necessarily mean that the data will end up on the disk. To get *all* of the data written so far into the file, you need to do any of the following:

1. `flush()` the file, or
2. `close()` the file, or
3. destroy the `QFile` instance (here by deleting `fd`).